# Unable to set Inventory Status for an Inventory Adjustment record using Suitescript 2.x

Tags: mapreduce, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am trying to create Inventory Adjustments from another record. I am successfully able to copy the inventory number, bin, and quantity, however I can't seem to capture the inventory status.

```
{
  {
    invAdjDetail.setCurrentSublistValue({
      sublistId: "inventoryassignment",
      fieldId: "toinventorystatus",
      value: invStatus,
    });

    invAdjDetail.setCurrentSublistValue({
      sublistId: "inventoryassignment",
      fieldId: "status",
      value: invStatus,
    });

    invAdjDetail.setCurrentSublistValue({
      sublistId: "inventoryassignment",
      fieldId: "inventorystatus",
      value: invStatus,
    });

    invAdjDetail.setCurrentSublistValue({
      sublistId: "inventoryassignment",
      fieldId: "binnumber",
      value: invBin,
    });

    invAdjDetail.setCurrentSublistValue({
      sublistId: "inventoryassignment",
      fieldId: "quantity",
      value: -1 * invQty,
    });

    invAdjDetail.commitLine({ sublistId: "inventoryassignment" });
  }
}

invAdj.commitLine({ sublistId: "inventory" });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hnwqo.png) Am I doing something incorrectly? I passed in a few fields in case the record browser was somehow not right, but none of them seem to work.

I have tried setting the inventory status field as

- inventorystatus => from NS record browser
- toinventorystatus => from NS record browser
- status => Trying it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it, I had to pass the inventory status in after I passed in the negative quantity.

Answer (score 0):

I had an identical issue as the above and couldn't get a good fix, but embarrassingly the issue wasn't the code, but an existing Item Adjustment.

Because I was testing the script in Sandbox I had already managed to create an IA for that transaction (I am running IA on IR's, to change lot numbers from TO's), and so once that IA was deleted my script ran fine and the stock was adjusted out again correctly.

May be worth checking that the stock you are trying to adjust out, still exists?

Tom